# How to return the indices of all the even entries in Matlab

Tags: matlab

given a vector v, I am to find the indices `idxeven` of all the even entries and return it as a vector.

```
v = [1 2 6 4 8 3 14 17 pi]
```

and I want to return:

```
idxeven = [2 3 4 5 7]
```

I have tried `idxeven=find(v)` but it simply returns the indices as a vector. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so you tried `idxeven=find(v)`. What if you tried `idxeven=find(evenv)` where `evenv` is `1` only where `v` is even and `0` otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

k = find(X) returns a vector containing the linear indices of each nonzero element in array X.

first create array X so as for even number in v X is one and zero for the others :

```
X=(mod(v,2)==0);
```

then use find to find desired indices :

```
idxeven=find(X);
```